# Which version of Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc is supported by .NETCoreApp v2.2?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

I am working on a Ubuntu 18.04 environment using Visual Studio Code and .NET Core v2.2.

After including a few existing projects into a solution that I'm working on, I ran into errors when I tried to compile stating that the namespace "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" could not be found.

So, I added a package reference for the projects that were complaining by using the dotnet CLI:

`dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc --version 3.0.20105.1`

But now when I try to `dotnet restore` or `dotnet msbuild` the solution file, I'm getting warnings reporting that:

```
warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 3.0.20105.1' was 
restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project 
target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'. 
This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

I would like to figure out which package version of `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` I need to install in order to be compatible with .NET Core v2.2.

I realize that this is just a warning and using the .NETFramework v4.6.1 may be okay, but I have been debugging a very strange issue that is only happening on a Ubuntu environment, so I would like to determine whether package versioning is a problem.

I have tried Google searching to determine which version of MVC is compatible with .NET Core 2.2, but I have yielded any useful results.

Does anyone know the answer to this question? Or would you be able to point me in the direction of a source that can answer it?

Comment: Version *3.0.20105.1* of [`Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/3.0.20105.1) is a 7 year old library and is not compatible with .NET Core at all. Why are you even trying to use it?

Comment: I think you need to include the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc and update the code appropriately to use the new namespace. Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc is not compatible with DotNetCore

Comment: David Glass is Bang On Target :-)

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee You've been digging to get my surname haha

Comment: @DavidG when I searched for a solution to resolve the missing namespace, the first result indicated I should use `Microsfot.AspNet.Mvc`. I did not realize there was a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`. Thanks @Soumen Mukherjee

Comment: Brand new to Asp development. I should have done a little more upfront investigation into the initial issue.

Comment: @DavidG we have interacted before in Stack some time back so I know you from then , indeed you have a very strong professional profile , appreciate that .